# ¿Por qué no puedo corregir el voto de cierre tras equivocarme?

Tags: soporte, cierre-de-preguntas, votos-de-cierre

Me he equivocado en el motivo de un voto de cierre y, cuando quiero cambiar el motivo, me sale un mensaje (tipo alert):

> ¿Estás seguro (no puedes volver a votar después de retractarte)?

*Sería bueno que uno se podría corregir antes de que se ejecute el cierre, más que nada para evitar las polémicas.*

Comment: No entiendo si estás preguntando si hay forma (no), o lo estás proponiendo como característica nueva para modificar en el sitio.

Comment: @Mariano - Quiero saber porque no es posible de corregir/cambiar el motivo... y ya según la respuesta (si es razonable o no)... pues proponerla

Comment: Veo que se ha pedido insistentemente: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=change+close+reason e incluso un CM lo vio como natural [en 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/919/209901): _Yeah, i'd like this too... Of course, if we could retract close votes, that would solve this problem as well._ (nota: lo de retraer ya se puede).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No se puede cambiar el motivo de un voto de cierre. Por el momento, si te equivocaste se puede retractar, pero no volver a votar... Es decir, no te equivoques porque se pierde la posibilidad de votar.

Como [comentó fedorqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2535/por-qu%C3%A9-no-puedo-corregir-el-voto-de-cierre-tras-equivocarme?noredirect=1#comment8905_2535), esto fue [pedido insistentemente en MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=change%20close%20reason). Entre los más destacados:

- [Grace period for changing close vote reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190090/304899)
  Solicita un período de 5 minutos en el cual se puede corregir.
- [Ability to change close reason before it gets closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/863/304899)
  Prácticamente lo mismo que estás pidiendo, respondido por [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) diciendo que también le gustaría.
- [We need to be able to vote to change the close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207768/304899)
  Solicita cambiar el motivo una vez cerrada.

No se me ocurre (ni encontré) ningún motivo de peso para impedirlo, por lo que simplemente supongo que pasa por poner en la balanza la dificultad de implementarlo con total trazabilidad, sabiendo que aplica a pocos casos.

Comment: O sea, se puede proponer en Meta y vas a tener mi voto, y probablemente el de muchos otros... Dudo que lo implementen por el momento.

Comment: Me gusta lo del periodo de 5 minutos (antes que este cerrado claro)... es igual  a las respuestas el cual tienes ese periodo sin que sea visible...(al menos para los usuarios _normales_)

Comment: @aldanux a mí también ;-)